# I have to double click the follow button to functioning this is due to using click event 2 time

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, click, buttonclick

I am working on follow button and with the help of JavaScript I've come up with the following code.

But the problem is I have to double click the follow button to  functioning this is due to using click event 2 time. I am open to better methods of solving this too.

```js
 
  var value = null;
    
const onClick = (event) => {
    // event.target.id
 
    value = event.target.id;
  console.log(value);
document.getElementById(`${value}`).addEventListener('click',function(){
    // console.log(value.id);
        if(this.classList.contains('follow')){
        this.classList.remove('follow');
       this.innerHTML ="Following";
       this.style.backgroundColor = 'green' ;
    }else{
        this.classList.add('follow');
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(27,18,83)' ;
        this.innerHTML="Follow";
    }
    })



}
window.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a double click event. You can check the if it satisfies your requirement.

MDN link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Comment: Actually for working my code Ihave to double click element and i just want to run it on single click plese help on this issue

Comment: Okay, got it. In your code snippet, you are adding a click listener on the window, so if user clicks anywhere on the window your onClick method is called. Inside the onClick method you are again adding a click listener on the element itself. That's why you need to double click to get your desired output.
If you just want to modify the follow button once user clicks on it, you can add a click event listener only on the button.

Comment: this will not work on multiple button like follow please provide code if possible for multiple button

Answer (score 0):

For multiple buttons with the same function, I would give all of them the same class (e.g. "btn"). Then in JS simply get all of the elements with this class, loop over the HTMLCollection which you would get and assign each element an eventlistener. When you want to change something on the button you have to use `event.target` in the function:

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (btn of buttons) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  
    if(event.target.classList.contains('follow')){
      event.target.classList.remove('follow');
      event.target.innerHTML ="Following";
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green' ;
    }else{
      event.target.classList.add('follow');
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(27,18,83)' ;
      event.target.innerHTML="Follow";
    }
    
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
```